# Does the body have specific mechanisms for healing burns, or is it general purpose stuff?

Tags: healing

I burned my thumb lighting sparklers (fireworks) a few nights ago. I've been pleased with how it's healing, and have been especially impressed because it's not a scenario that really could have come up in our evolutionary history. Then I started thinking that fires are not *that* common in nature. This prompts the question: do our bodies heal from burns using burn-specific techniques, or do they just follow general “procedures” for repairing damaged skin?

Comment: general applies to many specifics.